# Android Location.distanceTo(...) and Location.bearingTo(...) not returning correct results

Tags: android, location, distance, bearing

I've been though dozens of posts on this so please do not flag this as a duplicate because it isn't.

So running the following code:

```
private void testLocation(){
    double currentLat = 51.43376;
    double currentLng = -2.86221;

    double destLat = 51.43503; 
    double destLng = -2.86869;

    final float[] results= new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLng, destLat, destLng, results);
    Log.d("GPS", "results[0]: " + results[0]);
    Log.d("GPS", "results[1]: " + results[1]);
    Log.d("GPS", "results[2]: " + results[2]);


    Location here = new Location("Current");
    here.setLatitude(currentLat);
    here.setLatitude(currentLng);

    Location dest = new Location("Destination2");
    dest.setLatitude(destLat);
    dest.setLongitude(destLng);


    Log.d("GPS", "Bearing to dest: " + here.bearingTo(dest));
    Log.d("GPS", "Distance to dest: " + here.distanceTo(dest));
}
```

The output is:

```
04-19 13:39:55.850: D/GPS(12398): results[0]: 472.2533
04-19 13:39:55.860: D/GPS(12398): results[1]: -72.5882
04-19 13:39:55.860: D/GPS(12398): results[2]: -72.59327
04-19 13:39:55.860: D/GPS(12398): Bearing to dest: 120.83207
04-19 13:39:55.860: D/GPS(12398): Distance to dest: 7893878.5
```

The correct values should be:
    Distance 472.2533 (So results[0] is correct).
    Bearing 285.454 degrees

So I don't know what results[1] and results[2] are giving. And both bearingTo and distanceTo are giving completely the wrong answers.

This means that I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone help. Generally, all I want to do is calculate the distance and direction of a destination point from a current location point. If anyone has a better way for doing that than that shown above, or knows what I am doing wrong please help.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 4):

> The computed distance is stored in results`[0]`. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results`[1]`. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results`[2]` - [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29)

You're setting the latitude twice with two different values here:

```
here.setLatitude(currentLat);
here.setLatitude(currentLng);
```

And you mixed up the lat/long values here:

```
dest.setLongitude(destLat);
dest.setLatitude(destLng);
```

Check and see if that fixes your problems

The two methods of computing distance and bearing should produce identical results because the same method is used to compute those results. Look at [the source code of the SDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java#Location.distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29).

Comment: Thank for the reply. Sorted out mix up of lat/long but, still get incorrect results: `Bearing to dest: -2.2131138` and `Distance to dest: 6023135.0`. Even stranger. How can you have a negative bearing if it's supposed to be degrees east of true north?

Comment: For future respondees, what I really want is the bearing. I can get the distance from results[0].

Comment: @Adam Negative bearing is equivalent to degrees west of true north. See LimbSoup's answer too because he has a good point

Comment: @AdamDavies Also if you update your code snippet in the question, we might be able to see something else that's incorrect. It doesn't make sense that you would be getting different results for the two methods

Comment: BTW: what is the difference between the initial and the final bearing? When would they be different?

Comment: @Gavriel I don't know that I could explain it very well, but it has to do with the fact that you're calculating the shortest distance between two points traveled along the surface of a WGS84 ellipsoid. The altitude at different parts of the ellipsoid will vary. It doesn't treat the Earth as a perfect sphere.

Comment: @Samuel I was thinking of what could explain any difference between them. The only thing I can think of is that the initial is X and the final is X-360, so that it depends on whether I pass longitude 0. For example if I start from the west side of Greeenwich and head to east my initial bearing is 90, but when I pass the 0 longitude it'll become -270. But this is just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your own calculations for bearing are correct? `results[2]: -72.59327` is equivalent to 287.40673 Degrees.

Comment: Humm. So it would appear that if your bearing is between 180 and 360 the value is result[1] is a negative number so you have to do 360 - result[0]. Other wise it is a positive number and you can use it as is.

I still have no idea what the distanceTo method returns. Best to stay clear of that I suppose.